# How to make sure JQuery dynamically inject CSS properly and ready to use?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dynamic

I know that I can do this to inject CSS like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function() {
        $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css" type="text/css" />');
    });
});
```

But, this async.  i.e. even I append the link, there is no guarantee that the css is available at that time. (because of the CSS download)
so, if there is another js runs at the same time and try to aasign a class, then 
1) Will it still work?   Will the css applied later on after the file is fully downloaded?

If not, is there something like a call back or some trick that I can use to know that the css is fully downloaded?

Comment: "1) Will it still work? Will the css applied later on after the file is fully downloaded?" - yes and yes.

Comment: It seems like you could easily try it out and see if it works.

Comment: ok.. let me try.. Friday evening.. gonna get some beer.. and come back on Monday to try.  Thanks for telling me it may work. so that the word "CSS" will not floating in my mind while having beer. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need it guaranteed to be loaded and the CSS is definitely on the same domain, you could request the contents via Ajax and then inject the properties directly.

I've had good luck doing this (in iOS at least) by creating a dummy `<link>` element in the `<head>` and calling `text()` on it with the contents of the CSS file (as a string).

For example, roughly:

```
 $("a").click(function() {
        $.get('style2.css', function (data) { 
            $('link').text(data);
            // Stuff that must happen after CSS injection here
        });
    })
```

But honestly this is a rare use case.

Comment: Hmm. that's a very interest approach. I will try that. :)

Comment: it works. and I do some modification of the code.
If the css style is not found in the document's stylesheet, then I dynamically append a <link> tag in the header, and put the css data in it. :)

Comment: In my particular case, iOS would _not_ allow me to append a new link. Glad that works for you!